# what the default max length of rabbit queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

*For any given queue, the maximum length (of either type) can be defined using a policy (this option is highly recommended) or by clients using the queue's optional arguments. In the case where both the effective queue policy and arguments specify a maximum length, the minimum of the two values will be used.
Queue length settings also can be enforced by operator policies.*

https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

As we can see, the rabbitmq document has told us how to set the max-length of queues.  But I'd like to know what the default value of max-length is if we not do any changes.  is it no limit until my server's resources not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default maximum length of a RabbitMQ queue is unlimited, yes it has no limit until the server's resources are consumed.

If we set up length ourselves using `x-max-length` or using `management-console`, then we have to carefully consider the need of the application if queue is frequently reaching maximum length the oldest messages will be dopped